# Eigen binaryExpr with eigen type output

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm having a problem while trying to use binaryExpr. It is the first use I'm making of it so I have been following the [Eigen documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a1bf966395d085b345d952e3ee839236b)

For my use I need a functor with Eigen type inputs and outputs but this does not want to compile and I do not understand why. I've looked up the explanation in the code but I didn't think this would apply here because I use floats and an array of floats

```
// We require Lhs and Rhs to have "compatible" scalar types.
// It is tempting to always allow mixing different types but remember that this is often impossible in the vectorized paths.
// So allowing mixing different types gives very unexpected errors when enabling vectorization, when the user tries to
// add together a float matrix and a double matrix.
```

Here is a short example of the use I would need that gets me the same compilation error:

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

struct myBinaryFunctor {
  EIGEN_EMPTY_STRUCT_CTOR(myBinaryFunctor)
  typedef Vector2f result_type;
  Vector2f operator()(const Matrix<float,9,1>& a,const float& f) const
  {
      float x = a.head(4).sum()*f;
      float y = a.tail(5).sum()/f;
      return Vector2f(x,y);
  }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr int n = 3;
    Matrix<Matrix<float,9,1>,n,n> Ma;
    Matrix<float,n,n> F;
    Matrix<Vector2f,n,n> R;

    for(size_t i = 0, sizeMa = Ma.size(); i<sizeMa; i++)
    {
        Ma(i).setOnes();
    }

    F.setConstant(n,n,2);

    R = Ma.binaryExpr(F,myBinaryFunctor());

    return 0;
}
```

The compilation output is :

```
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/CwiseBinaryOp.h:107: erreur : static assertion failed: YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY
       EIGEN_CHECK_BINARY_COMPATIBILIY(BinaryOp,typename Lhs::Scalar,typename Rhs::Scalar);
       ^
```

If you have a solution that could make this work this would be a huge help for me :) If not I would still enjoy an explanation to understand what is happening. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding:

```
namespace Eigen {
template<>
struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<Matrix<float,9,1>,float,myBinaryFunctor> {
  typedef Vector2f ReturnType;
};
}
```

will do the job. This is because implicit scalar conversion are explicitly disallowed within Eigen, so you must explicit say that two different scalar types are compatible. For instance adding a `VectorXd` to a `VectorXf` is disallowed.

Nonetheless, it seems to me that your abusing Eigen's features here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I never thought of explicitly telling Eigen to allow this operation. I'm not sure what you mean by "abusing Eigen's features" though. Using unary and binary Expr seems to be the most explicit way to do what I want. 
To me it looks a lot better than raw loops because I do not have to think about access order and I can give an explicit name to the functor. 
I don't know why but it seems to be more efficient than the raw loops too.